# Searching for different columns in different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I execute this two queries one by one but i need to execute this two queries as one query same time and get result from mysql database once

I tried UNION SELECT but because of select different coulmns (model,modelsnumber) from different tables it's not working

Does anybody knows sql query structure to help me to solve this problem?

## query 1

```
$query = "SELECT post_id,SUBSTR(post_name, 1 ,30) as post_name,price,username,poster_folder_id FROM realestate 
    USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_name,idx_price,idx_username,idx_poster_folder_id)
    WHERE post_name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

## query 2

```
$query = "SELECT post_id,SUBSTR(post_name, 1 ,30) as post_name,price,username,poster_folder_id FROM cars 
USE INDEX(idx_post_id,idx_name,idx_price,idx_username,idx_poster_folder_id)
WHERE post_name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR model LIKE ? OR modelsnumber LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

I tried

```
$query = "SELECT post_id,SUBSTR(post_name, 1 ,30) as post_name,price,username,poster_folder_id FROM realestate 
WHERE post_name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT post_id,SUBSTR(post_name, 1 ,30) as post_name,price,username,poster_folder_id FROM cars 
WHERE post_name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR model LIKE ? OR modelsnumber LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: @Akina UNION SELECT not working at all i need different sql query structure

Comment: Could you explain why downvote?

Comment: What are you talking about, _“i need different sql query structure”_? The column list is identical in both queries (and I guess we can assume they are of the same types as well?), and _that_ is the criterion for whether or not you can combine two result sets via UNION.

Comment: *but because of select different coulmns (model,modelsnumber) from different tables* ??? Output lists in your separate queries are absolutely the same.

Comment: _“but because of select different coulmns (model,modelsnumber) from different tables it's not working”_ - you are not _selecting_ those columns, you are using them in your WHERE clause. That’s two totally different things to begin with.

Comment: The index is not likely to be useful for the query.  You should just leave it out.

Comment: add a placeholder for the missing column in the dependent query when using union all

Answer (score 1):

Separate subqueries with ORDER BY and/or LIMIT in UNION **must be enclosed with parenthesis**:

```php
$query = "
   (SELECT post_id,SUBSTR(post_name, 1 ,30) as post_name,price,username,poster_folder_id 
    FROM realestate 
    WHERE post_name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10
   )
UNION
   (SELECT post_id,SUBSTR(post_name, 1 ,30) as post_name,price,username,poster_folder_id 
    FROM cars 
    WHERE post_name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR model LIKE ? OR modelsnumber LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 10
   )";
```